# DynamoDB client select specific column

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

my DynamoDB table looks like this,

```
|--PK--|--SK---|--status--|--body--|---time--|--picture--|
|--2---|-#BAR1-|--false---|-JSON*--|--Sunday-|--x0415456-|
|--2---|-#BAR2-|--true----|-JSON*--|--Monday-|-923523525-|
|--3---|-#TEMP-|--true----|-JSON*--|--Friday-|-xyfsdf3c--|
```

my code:

```
    const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    const params = {
        TableName: process.env.DB_TABLE_NAME,
        KeyConditionExpression: 'PK = :pk AND begins_with(SK, :sk)',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ':pk': input,
          ':sk': '#BAR'
        }
    }

    const res = await documentClient.query(params).promise();
```

it returns all data like `PK, SK, status, body, time, picture`

I want to select only  `SK, status, and body`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DB_TABLE_NAME,
    KeyConditionExpression: 'PK = :pk AND begins_with(SK, :sk)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':pk': input,
      ':sk': '#BAR'
    },
    ProjectionExpression: "SK, status, body",
}

const res = await documentClient.query(params).promise();
```

Comment: ProjectionExpression doesn't  work it return an internal error

Comment: my bad, I'm using DynamoDB reserve word status that's why I'm getting error